# "This" keyword inside a method in Java

Tags: java, keyword

I'm having an issue with **this** inside a method:

```
 public Time getArrivalTime()
 {
   Time temp = this;
   temp.doSomeThing();
   return temp;
 }
```

I want to use method doSomeThing() only on temp, but somehow I use this methon also on **this** obj.
Can someone explane me please where is my mistake?

Comment: Since `temp` *is* `this`, what do you think "only on temp" would mean in this case?

Comment: probably you want something line `Time temp = this.clone();`

Comment: or `Time temp = new Time(this);` if the class has a copy-constructor.

Comment: I forgot about aliasing...Thank you!